# How to call Postgres function returning SETOF record?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have written the following function:

```
    -- Gets stats for all markets
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GetMarketStats (
)
RETURNS SETOF record
AS
$$
BEGIN
 SELECT 'R approved offer' AS Metric,
 SUM(CASE WHEN M.MarketName = 'A+' AND M.Term = 24 THEN LO.Amount ELSE 0 end) AS MarketAPlus24,
 SUM(CASE WHEN M.MarketName = 'A+' AND M.Term = 36 THEN LO.Amount ELSE 0 end) AS MarketAPlus36,
 SUM(CASE WHEN M.MarketName = 'A' AND M.Term = 24 THEN LO.Amount ELSE 0 end) AS MarketA24,
 SUM(CASE WHEN M.MarketName = 'A' AND M.Term = 36 THEN LO.Amount ELSE 0 end) AS MarketA36,
 SUM(CASE WHEN M.MarketName = 'B' AND M.Term = 24 THEN LO.Amount ELSE 0 end) AS MarketB24,
 SUM(CASE WHEN M.MarketName = 'B' AND M.Term = 36 THEN LO.Amount ELSE 0 end) AS MarketB36
FROM "Market" M
 INNER JOIN "Listing" L ON L.MarketID = M.MarketID
 INNER JOIN "ListingOffer" LO ON L.ListingID = LO.ListingID;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And when trying to call it like this...

```
select * from GetMarketStats() AS (
   Metric VARCHAR(50),
   MarketAPlus24 INT,  
   MarketAPlus36 INT,
   MarketA24 INT,
   MarketA36 INT,
   MarketB24 INT,
   MarketB36 INT);
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "getmarketstats" line 2 at SQL statement
```

I don't understand this output. I've tried using perform too, but I thought one only had to use that if the function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function doesn't maken sense, it doesn't return anything. It looks like a VIEW, so why don't you create a view?

Edit:
You have use the OUT parameters or RETURN TABLE() with the parameters:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_func(OUT o_id INT, OUT o_bar TEXT) 
RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT id, bar FROM foo;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT  * FROM my_func();
```

Comment: I come from a SQL Server world. I expected similar behaviour where any SELECT statement is returned. I'll try changing to a view. Thanks

Comment: Assuming I did want to pass a parameter, how do I go about returning the result of my SQL query?

Comment: See example, RETURNS TABLE(int, text) would be another option.

Comment: The point that addresses the actual question is the use of "RETURN QUERY" to make the following SELECT's result set the result of the function. The OUT parameters/RETURNS TABLE just make invocation a lot easier.