# pgtap: expected and obtained result are equal, yet the test fails

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, pgtap

i use [pgtap](http://pgtap.org/) to test postgresql stored procedures. its [results_eq](http://pgtap.org/documentation.html#results_eq) function takes the result of a stored procedure, compares it to an expected result and reports failure if both are not equal.

this is the code i am running:

```
PREPARE result_have AS SELECT select_some_data(12345, 'test_string');
PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)');
SELECT results_eq('result_have', 'result_want');
```

and this is the failure output:

```
not ok 21
# Failed test 21: "this should return a result"
#     Columns differ between queries:
#         have: ("(""2010-09-07 06:05:00+00"",100.0)")
#         want: ("(""2010-09-07 06:05:00+00"",100.0)")
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 21
```

i might be really sleep-deprived, but want and have look pretty similar to me.

does anyone know why this is reported as failure ?

---

**update** concerning details: this is how i define the stored procedure in question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_some_data
(
    IN p_some_pkey integer,
    IN p_some_code varchar(16)
)
RETURNS TABLE(timestamp_utc timestamp with time zone, value varchar)
  ...
```

so to follow [peters advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323844/pgtap-expected-and-obtained-result-are-equal-yet-the-test-fails/7326387#7326387), i tried changing my code, but had no success:

```
PREPARE result_have AS SELECT select_some_data(12345, 'test_string');
-- TODO: none of these work, syntax error at or near "TABLE"
-- PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)'::TABLE(timestamp with time zone, varchar));
-- PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)'::'TABLE(timestamp with time zone, varchar)');
-- this is the old code...
PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)');

SELECT results_eq('result_have', 'result_want');
```

as you can probably tell, i'm pretty much stabbing in the dark even about basic postgresql syntax - and neither google nor the search on postgresql.org return anything useful when searching for `::`. i eventually hazarded a lucky guess that this might be an operator and found `::` being a [type cast](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS). The `column_name` parameter documentation for [CREATE FUNCTION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) says that '`RETURNS TABLE` also implies `RETURNS SETOF`' which gets me e.g. [here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions) and maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955167/postgresql-return-setof-record-virtual-table) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983501/how-to-call-postgres-function-returning-setof-record). New attempts:

```
PREPARE result_have AS SELECT select_some_data(12345, 'test_string');
-- TODO: doesn't work, syntax error at or near "("
-- PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)'::SETOF(timestamp with time zone, varchar));
-- TODO: doesn't work, syntax error at or near ","
-- PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)'::SETOF RECORD(timestamp with time zone, varchar));
-- this is the old code...
PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)');

SELECT results_eq('result_have', 'result_want');
```

this is pointless, i'm just doing guesswork here. can anybody help me out with the right syntax ? please also note that the function just `RETURNS TABLE` because that was the very first thing i was able to get to work, so if there is a solution that would require changing that, i'm happy to change it.

---

**update 2**: RhodiumToad on the postgresql IRC channel(irc://irc.freenode.net/#postgresql) helped me out with the proper syntax. if i knew a little more about postgresql than i do, i could have figured that this only makes sense: two data types, two casts (DOH!) :o).

also, at the moment, there is only one data set in the test database, so the syntax as used above might still work. from all i understand, it will probably fail once there is more than one dataset returned, so it should be `SELECT * FROM`, not just `SELECT`:

```
PREPARE result_have AS SELECT * FROM select_some_data(12345, 'test_param_code');
PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('2010-09-07 06:05:00+00'::timestamp with time zone, '100.0'::varchar);

SELECT results_eq('result_have', 'result_want', 'have and want should be equal');
```

now have and want results are compared as equal and the test passes. log output when the tests are run:

```
ok 21 - have and want should be equal
ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=21,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.05 cusr  0.03 csys =  0.10 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

WOOT!! :-)

Comment: hmmm, no that i look at this again, i realize that the second column in the table the function returns is a varchar, whereas pgtap reports a float. weird...

Comment: @mu is too short: i'm not sure there are any microseconds in either result_have nor result_want; after all, if they were in there, they would get displayed, wouldn't they ? but then, i do see timestamps with and without microseconds all over the place and so far, i wasn't really able to figure out why they're sometimes in there and sometimes not. so far, it hasn't really mattered...

Comment: Thanks, @past_self for putting this up! :+1: 8 years later, same problem - syntax and quoting still suck and there's still no alternative in terms of PostgreSQL unit testing frameworks. Glad I found some help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't give all the details, but I suspect it's a data type mismatch.  pgTAP tends to require exact matches.  Try this:

```
PREPARE result_want AS VALUES ('("2010-09-07 06:05:00+00",100.0)'::foo);
```

where `foo` is the return type of the function `select_some_data`.